# MVC - Adding values from input text in my view to db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im a newbie with MVC and im having trouble adding the values of my input text to a viewmodel i created. Here is what i have so far.

The only thing that it does is reload my page and not really inserting values to my VM. And im also getting error that my input string was not in a correct format.

[UPDATE]
**My ViewModel PO_OrderList**

```
public class PO_OrderList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Qty { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}

public class PO_OrderListContext : DBContext
{
    public DbSet<PO_OrderList> poOrderList { get; set; }
}
```

**My view where i input my values**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddtopoOrderList", "PurchaseOrder", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <td><input type="text" name="Qty" id="txtqty" maxlength="2" size="3" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /></td>
            <td>
                <select name="ProductName" id="ProductName">
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.productList)
                    {
                        <option id=@item.ProductID value="@item.UnitPrice" data-desc="@item.Description"> @item.ProductName </option>
                    }
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtdescription" name="Description" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtunitprice" name="Price" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtamount" name="Amount" /></td>

            //Button that will submit values in this from to Controller
            <td><input type="submit" id="btnAdd" value="ADD" /></td> 
        }
```

**MY Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddtopoOrderList(string Qty, string ProductName, string Description, string UnitPrice, string Amount)
    {
        POdb.poOrderList.Add(new PO_OrderList 
        { 
            Qty = Convert.ToInt32(Qty),
            ProductName = ProductName,
            Description = Description,
            UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt16(UnitPrice),
            Amount = Convert.ToInt16(Amount)
        });

        POdb.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Generate you view correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods (`@Html.DropDownListFor()`, `@Html.TextBoxFor()` etc) and change you method to `public ActionResult AddtopoOrderList(PO_OrderList model). You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to learn the basics.

Comment: Im actually using Jquery to change the values of my textbox depending on the selected item on my dropdownlist. If i use @Html.TextBoxFor(), how do i add and id to it

Comment: The `HtmlHelpers` generate an `id` attribute (that matches the name of you property)

Answer (score 0):

Change the button type to submit
    input type="submit" id="btnAdd" ...

Comment: thank you for this! please view my update cos the values are still not inserting

Comment: OP's `txtunitprice` should be corrected: `<input type="text" id="txtunitprice" name="UnitPrice" />`. All name attributes from view elements should be same with model property name to bind them.

Answer (score 0):

The better way of doing this is bind your `Properties` into your form and get them on your controller like below :

```
    @using(Html.BeginForm("AddtopoOrderList", "PurchaseOrder", FormMethod.Post)) {
        <td>
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Qty, new{maxlength="2", size="3", onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" }
</td>
........ 
< td > <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" value="ADD" /> < /td> 
    }
```

and get the form value at your `Controller` `ActionResult` like below:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult AddtopoOrderList(PO_OrderList model) {
     // you will get all your form value into your model
     // Do your logic here
     return View();
 }
```

But if you still want to follow your current approach, then you have to follow `FormCollection` approach like below:

> //Remain your HTML as same way

Change your `ActionResult` like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddtopoOrderList(FormCollection formData) {
    int Qty = Convert.ToInt32(formData["QTY"].toString()); // you wil get your Input values into formData
    // Do your logic here
    return View();
}
```

Hope my code will helps you

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

yes better way is change textbox in razor view @Html.TextboxFor bind automaticaly or other way is 
you can add

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddtopoOrderList(string Qty, string ProductName, string Description, string Price, string Amount)
{
    POdb.poOrderList.Add(new PO_OrderList 
    { 
        Qty = Convert.ToInt32(Qty),
        ProductName = ProductName,
        Description = Description,
        UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt16(UnitPrice),
        Amount = Convert.ToInt16(Amount)
    });

    POdb.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

pls give parameter name same as textbox name you given then its work fines